# Publishing a .NET Core project to Nuget - which framework version to use?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

## TL;DR version

I'm building a .NET Core lib targeting the framework `netstandard1.6` + `dnxcore50` in the `project.json`. My binaries are built into folders with matching names. [MSDN's Nuget naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks) says that `dnxcore50` is a "deprecated" framework - so should I just rename my folder to `netcore50` or should I target another framework altogether?

I'm using VS 2015 Community and the DotNetCore.1.0.1 SDK.

## Long version

I maintain an FTP library called [FluentFTP](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP). I've successfully compiled a version for .NET core using VS 2015 Community. My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.IO": "4.3.0.0",
    "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.3.0.0",
    "System.Net.Sockets": "4.3.0.0",
    "System.Net.Security": "4.3.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
    }
  }
}
```

I copied another project's `frameworks` section since I didn't know what format to use. As you can see I'm targeting .NET Core 5.0 (apparently) and .NET Standard 1.6. I can build successfully, so I'm assuming I have built a .NET Standard 1.6 and .NET Core 5.0 version (am I right?). When I build, I get a directory structure like:

- dnxcore50
- netstandard1.6
- net20
- net40

**In order to publish a multi-framework lib to nuget, MSDN says you need to follow a certain [naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks)**.

Sadly `dnxcore50` is marked as a "Deprecated Frameworks" in the [naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks) article. Does that mean that:

1. I'm building for a wrong/outdated type of framework?
2. I just need to rename the folder `dnxcore50` to `netcore50` and publish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just publish it with the folder called `dnxcore50`.** While its a slightly older naming convention, the lib will still be installable in .NET Core projects created VS 2015. I've tested it and it works. To verify it independently, try installing [FluentFTP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP) in a .NET Core project via the "Manage Nuget Packages for this Project" dialog in VS 2015.

**Edit:** For VS 2017 see [solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856619/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-dnxcore-version-v5-0-were-not-found/42856620#42856620).

Comment: Does it also work with VS2017, which uses a new project system for .Net Core?

Comment: @svick - See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856619/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-dnxcore-version-v5-0-were-not-found/42856620#42856620

Answer (score 0):

A am afraid this is nothing but my opinion (a matter of philosophy actually) though I feel like it can be considered a relevant answer to the question:

In general you should require what you actually make use of and no more. This means the oldest versions of the framework and the language whose features you use. Provided is fully compatible with newer versions (ideally you should regularly test your code on all the newer framework versions too in this case). In case it is not but you still want to support it (because you and/or other people falling into your target audience are still using it in legacy code support perhaps) you should consider building separate versions for different platforms, some times this may even mean maintaining parallel versions of some parts of the code.

I don't mean you should intentionally limit yourself in features you use just to support an older framework and/or language (that's a matter of a separate, heavily subjective and context-dependent question). I just mean the case like when one have coded the entire project in C# 3.0 on a Windows XP machine, then his company buys him new and shiny laptop with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 and he starts building against .NET Framework 4.6.2 alone just because he can although he even doesn't know a single new feature added in this framework.

What I would consider a reasonable exception from the philosophy described above are pre-release (alpha, beta, ctp, rc etc) versions of the frameworks - **exactly your case, as far as I understand**. As soon as the release is published a developer should better switch to it as soon as possible (but not sooner ©).

However, wherever reason and flexibility come together with attempts to reach practical (or a little bit higher) degree of logical formalism (for sake of more efficient decision making) exceptions from exceptions emerge, in this case these are:

1. Think twice before dropping support for whatever is still used widely. In the real world cases occur when an older/pre-release version is adopted much more widely than a newer/release version and there may be breaking changes between the versions that encumber the upgrade process objectively. **This may happen to be your case too**, I don't really know how serious (how much work is needed to upgrade the existing code) the changes in this case are, how much people are using the old framework version as by now, how important are the modifications you have introduced in your library new version (e.g. if it contains serious bug fixes or new features that are of actually great use and/or make the migration to the new framework easier).
2. If this is doesn't take any significant amount of time, effort, freedom (e.g. to use new framework/language features you want) and other resources from you keep supporting even the obsolete stuff as long as at least some people choose to keep using it. If you feel like you begin failing to enjoy supporting that, it can be kind to send the remaining users an end-of-support notification letter and/or publish it in your blog, twitter etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely remove dnxcore50. Ideally you should only provide .NET Standard version, but you might also include .NET Framework (netXX).

See a famous example ANTLR,

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/7077054ddc5fab977a9b20b971aef6798563f486/build/Antlr4.Runtime.nuspec