# .NET Core - The reference assemblies for framework "DNXCore,Version=v5.0" were not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I'm getting this error when migrating a .NET core lib (DNXCore50) from VS 2015 to VS 2017.

> The reference assemblies for framework "**DNXCore**,Version=v5.0" were not found.

My project file currently looks like this: (after the VS 2017 migration wizard migrated my "project.json" to a .csproj file)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>An FTP and FTPS library for .NET, optimized for speed. Provides extensive FTP commands, file uploads/downloads, SSL/TLS connections and FTP proxies.</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>16.3.0</VersionPrefix>
    <Authors>J.P. Trosclair;Harsh Gupta</Authors>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;dnxcore50</TargetFrameworks>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);CORE</DefineConstants>
    <RootNamespace>FluentFTP</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FluentFTP</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PackageId>FluentFTP</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>DNXCore</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>false</GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Sockets" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Security" Version="4.3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm getting the above mentioned error when I compile. Things I've tried:

- Using **.NETPortable v5.0** instead. Too many missing classes here.
- Using **.NETCoreApp v1.0** instead. Every class is missing. Did I use a wrong version?
- Using **DNXCore**. No missing classes. Just one error from VS.

What should I use instead of DNXCore 5.0? I need the latest APIs like `TlsStream` and `Uri`, stuff not present Or is there a way to force the compiler to compile? Please note this was a working library when I used VS 2015 to compile. Now that I've switched to VS 2017 I cannot compile my project anymore! in either .NET Core or .NET Portable.

Comment: Usually a socket related library should only require 1.3. I am not sure why for yours 1.6 is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's surprising!

My lib successfully compiled with **.NETStandard v1.6**!

Including my XML here in case anyone else has this issue:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>An FTP and FTPS library for .NET, optimized for speed. Provides extensive FTP commands, file uploads/downloads, SSL/TLS connections and FTP proxies.</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>16.3.0</VersionPrefix>
    <Authors>J.P. Trosclair;Harsh Gupta</Authors>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;dnxcore50</TargetFrameworks>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);CORE</DefineConstants>
    <RootNamespace>FluentFTP</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FluentFTP</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PackageId>FluentFTP</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETStandard</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>false</GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Sockets" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Security" Version="4.3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`dnxcore50` is no longer used as a TargetFramework.  You can see the [1.1.0 documentation for netstandard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/release/1.1.0/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#deprecated-monikers) that lists it as a deprecated moniker.

For the latest .NET Standard documentation, see the [.NET Standard FAQ](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md).

You can just completely drop the 2nd TFM all together.  `netstandard1.6` will work on .NET Core just fine.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>An FTP and FTPS library for .NET, optimized for speed. Provides extensive FTP commands, file uploads/downloads, SSL/TLS connections and FTP proxies.</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>16.3.0</VersionPrefix>
    <Authors>J.P. Trosclair;Harsh Gupta</Authors>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);CORE</DefineConstants>
    <RootNamespace>FluentFTP</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FluentFTP</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PackageId>FluentFTP</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>false</GenerateNeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Sockets" Version="4.3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Security" Version="4.3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also removed setting the `TargetFrameworkIdentifier` and  `TargetFrameworkVersion` since those properties are inferred from `TargetFramework`.